# Word-counter won't print foreign characters

Tags: python, word-count

How can i set it to print chinese and accented characters?

```
from twill.commands import *
from collections import Counter

with open('names.txt') as inf:
    words = (line.strip() for line in inf)
    freqs = Counter(words)
    print (freqs)
```

Comment: Which version of Python are you using?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3883573/encoding-error-in-python-with-chinese-characters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To deal correctly with chinese characters I'd use `codecs.open` instead of plain `open`, and pass it the right encoding for the file.

For example if you have a file "unicode.txt" containing the string "aèioሴ ሴ":

```
>>> open('unicode.txt').read()    # has utf-8 BOM
'\xef\xbb\xbfa\xc3\xa8io\xe1\x88\xb4 \xe1\x88\xb4'
>>> codecs.open('unicode.txt').read()    #without encoding is the same as open
'\xef\xbb\xbfa\xc3\xa8io\xe1\x88\xb4 \xe1\x88\xb4'
>>> codecs.open('unicode.txt', encoding='utf-8').read()
u'\ufeffa\xe8io\u1234 \u1234'
```

And for the `Counter`s you obtain:

```
>>> Counter(open('unicode.txt').read())
Counter({'\xe1': 2, '\x88': 2, '\xb4': 2, 'a': 1, '\xc3': 1, ' ': 1, 'i': 1, '\xa8': 1, '\xef': 1, 'o': 1, '\xbb': 1, '\xbf': 1})
>>> Counter(codecs.open('unicode.txt', encoding='utf-8').read())
Counter({u'\u1234': 2, u'a': 1, u' ': 1, u'i': 1, u'\xe8': 1, u'o': 1, u'\ufeff': 1})
```

*If* for "How can I set it to print chinese characters" you mean that `print(freqs)`  should show something like `Counter({'不': 1})`, then this is not possible in python2, while it's the default on python3.

In python2 the `Counter`'s `__str__` method class the `__repr__` method of the strings, and thus you'll always see something like `\u40ed` instead of the real character:

```
>>> Counter(u'不')
Counter({u'\u4e0d': 1})
>>> repr(u'不')
"u'\\u4e0d'"
```

In python3 all strings are unicode and the `repr` of '不' is "'不'":

```
>>> Counter('不')
Counter({'不': 1})
>>> repr('不')
"'不'"
```

So if you want a solution that works on both python2 and python3 you should create a function `str_counter` that, in python3 just returns the `str` of `Counter`, while in python2 it must iterate over key and value pairs and build the string representation itself:

```
>>> def str_counter(counter):
...     if sys.version_info.major > 2:
...         # python3, no need to do anything
...         return str(counter)
...     # python2: we manually create a unicode representation.
...     result = u'{%s}'
...     parts = [u'%s: %s' % (unicode(key), unicode(value)) for key, value in counter.items()]
...     return result % u', '.join(parts)
... 
>>> print str_counter(Counter(u'不'))   # python2
{不: 1}
```