# Unable to read chinese character from XML file in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unicode

Here is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16" standalone="no"?>
<table rows="3" cols="8" style="" render="1" datatype="2" tabletype="dynamictable1int" primary="" assetClass="Fixed Income" bookName="2015-05-20 LM BW GFI_CN" languageCode="12" languageWord="Chinese">
    <tbody>
        <row condition="TCH">
            <entry></entry>
            <entry> 1 个月 </entry>
            <entry> 3 个月 </entry>
            <entry> 1 年 </entry>
            <entry> 3 年 </entry>
            <entry> 5 年 </entry>
            <entry> 10 年 </entry>
            <entry> 从创建之日起 </entry>
        </row>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

When I am trying to run through this XMl the values I get,

```
['1 ä¸ªæœˆ', '3 ä¸ªæœˆ', '1 å¹´', '3 å¹´', '5 å¹´', '10 å¹´', 'ä»Žåˆ›å»ºä¹‹æ—¥èµ·']
```

I am using python3,

```
table = XMLTable(xml, text_columns='ALL')
categoryNames = row2[0][1:]
```

When I tried to find the type of categoryNames I found it is returning `<class,'str'>`

I want this characters to come in Chinese as I am using them as Category Names for my bar chart, I am using reportlab to generate the chart. It is rendering the same values as the one I have shown above. While when I am running the same code using python 2.7 it is rendering perfectly.

Here is the code for XMLTable-

```
class XMLTable:
    error = object()    #unique

    @verboseError
    def __init__(self, xml, text_columns=[], floatDefault=0):
        xml = xml.replace('<emphasis>','',1000)
        xml = xml.replace('</emphasis>','',1000)
        xml = xml.replace('<para>','',1000)               
        xml = xml.replace('</para>','',1000)
        xml = xml.replace('<sub>','',1000)
        xml = xml.replace('</sub>','',1000)
        xml = xml.replace('<sup>','',1000)
        xml = xml.replace('</sup>','',1000)
        xml = xml.replace('<superscript>','',1000)
        xml = xml.replace('</superscript>','',1000)
        xml = xml.replace('<emphasis>','',1000)
        xml = xml.replace('</emphasis>','',1000)
        xml = xml.replace('<sbr>','',1000)
        xml = xml.replace('</sbr>','',1000)
        self.xml = xml
        self.data = []

        #print xml
        #pdb.set_trace()
        self.tree = pyRXPU.Parser().parse(xml)
        self.tags = dict()
        self.tags.update(self.tree[1])
        self.tableTag = NonEscapingTagWrapper(self.tree)
        if hasattr(self.tableTag, 'assetClass'):
            self.assetClass = self.tableTag.assetClass
        else:
            self.assetClass = None
        for i, row in enumerate(self.tableTag.tbody):
            if hasattr(row, 'selrow') and row.selrow == '0': continue
            newRow = []
            for col_no, entry in enumerate(row):
                if hasattr(entry, 'selcol') and entry.selcol == '0':
                    continue
                value = stripTags(tt2xml(entry._children))
                if text_columns != 'ALL':
                    if col_no not in text_columns:
                        v = re.sub(r"[^-\d\.]",'', value)
                        try:
                            value = float(v)
                        except ValueError:
                            if floatDefault is XMLTable.error:
                                annotateException('\nrow=%d col=%d value=%r cannot be converted to float' % (i,col_no,value))
                            else:
                                value = floatDefault
                newRow.append(value)
            self.data.append(newRow)

    @verboseError
    def getFormat(self, row, col):
        value = str(self.tableTag.tbody[row][col])
        return getNumberFormat(value)
    @verboseError
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data)

    @verboseError
    def __iter__(self):
        return self.data.__iter__()

    @verboseError
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if isinstance(key, int):
            return self.data[key]
        elif isinstance(key, slice):
            return self.data[key]
        else:
            return self.tags[key]

    @verboseError
    def __setitem__(self, key, item):
        if isinstance(key, int):
            self.data[key] = item
        elif isinstance(key, slice):
            self.data[key] = item
        else:
            self.tags[key] = item

    @verboseError
    def __delitem__(self, key):
        if isinstance(key, int):
            del self.data[key]
        elif isinstance(key, slice):
            del self.data[key]
        else:
            del self.tags[key]

    @verboseError
    def keys(self):
        return self.tags.keys()

    @verboseError
    def items(self):
        return self.tags.items()

    @verboseError
    def get(self, key, default=None):
        if key in self.tags.keys():
            return self.tags[key]
        if default:
            return default
        raise KeyError('there is no such key %s'%key)
    @verboseError
    def __str__(self):
        return self.xml

    @verboseError
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.tree)

    @verboseError
    def clean(self, remove_if_zeros=None):
        for row in self.data:
            if row[remove_if_zeros] == 0:
                self.data.remove(row)
        return self
```

Comment: Where are you getting your `XMLTable()` from?

Comment: XMlTable is my own parser script. I am adding the script as well in the question itself.

Comment: I hope this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3883573/encoding-error-in-python-with-chinese-characters

Comment: and this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2688020/how-to-print-chinese-word-in-my-code-using-python

Comment: In both the stackoverflow answers they decoded the string but we cant decode the string over here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to open xml file with encoding format?
for example.
file name: **abc.xml**

```
xml = open(abc, encoding="utf-8").read()
```

this is worked for me.

Comment: It worked, even I was getting the same error while writing to XML.